# Fastapi async sql unique constraint throws Internal Server Error. Instead of returning a error message

Tags: python, sql, fastapi

I am using FastAPI and Async SQl. I have defined the schema with email unique. But when I pass the same email to the FastAPI route. It throws error on development server
`sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email` and returns a 500 Internal response via Postman. I want to show error as a message and not 500 error what should I do ?

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I am at the same point, for now my solution is an extra query to check if the user exists and if so, to raise a HTTPException with Status 409 and an individual message via the detail attribute.

```
@app.post("/users", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=schemas.UserOut)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    existing_user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == user.email).first()
    if not existing_user:
        user.password = hashPassword(user.password)
        new_user = models.User(**user.model_dump())
        db.add(new_user)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(new_user)  # this is like the returning *
        return new_user
raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail=f"User with email does already exist"
```

Answer (score -3):

what is happening is an Error that the client should NOT have access to,
there is a difference between validation errors that YOU define and between the ORM and database engine errors the library shows, 
what you should do is check why are you sending a database query with an empty email! if you do so, the SQL engine will tell you that you can not put a NULL value there, which is something you did set.
there should be a validation before sending the query to the DB,
in FastApi, such validation should be done with Pydantic models. 
EDIT: 
thanks to @Mecid X Recebli for his comment, I think the question has been changed and my answer is no longer valid. \

I answered as if you are sending an empty value of email to DB query, but your question says that you are sending a duplicate email,
you should do email validation in the Pydantic schema, and that is by querying the DB for that email, if you have an account with the same email, raise a validation exception inside the validation method in the pydantic shema.

Comment: That does not answer OP question. He does not insert a row with empty email but a row with an email that already exist in that bale column